# Div on top of flash without wmode

Tags: css, flash

I have an AD which is basically a flash file inside an IFRAME. Unfortunately, I cannot control the wmode of the flash file.

Is there any way in which I can place the div on top of the flash?

**UPDATE**: How does Wibiya (wibiya.com) do it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an iframe cut-out hack which is supported in many browsers for backwards compatibility reasons.

http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/notes/2009/07/windowed-windowless-plugins.html

Add an absolutely positioned empty iframe with the proper dimensions that acts as a mask wherever you want the underlying HTML to "bleed-through". That's probably how Wibiya is doing it, although I haven't taken a look.

Closure provides a helper class to do this type of thing if you're looking for inspiration: http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/ui/iframemask.js

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  Windowless objects are rendered on a different "plane" to windowed objects (such as ActiveX controls, in the case of IE).  Microsoft's explanation obviously applies only to Internet Explorer, but other browsers appear to work in a similar way.

> All windowed elements paint themselves on top of all windowless
>   elements, despite the wishes of their
>   container. However, windowed elements
>   do follow the **z-index** attribute with
>   respect to each other, just as
>   windowless elements follow the **z-index**
>   attribute with respect to each other.
>
> All windowless elements are rendered
>   on the same MSHTML plane, and windowed
>   elements draw on a separate MSHTML
>   plane. You can use **z-index** to
>   manipulate elements on the same plane
>   but not to mix and match with elements
>   in different planes. You can rearrange
>   the z-indexing of the elements on each
>   plane, but the windowed plane always
>   draws on the top of the windowless
>   plane.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177378

This is actually a benefit to the advertising service - it prevents publishers from masking, covering and slightly altering their ads (for instance, putting an image in front of the ad to make it blend in with the site).